# Update or insert element in array (If not exists) MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo db collection using the bucket pattern

example:

```
{
    "clientId" : "some-client-id",
    "count": "3",
    "properties" : [
        {
            "key" : "prop1",
            "value" : "value1
        },
         {
            "key" : "prop2",
            "value" : "value2
        },
        {
            "key": "prop3"
            "value": "value3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to perform a bulk update or insertion operation based on an array of properties. This operation should update the collection by inserting elements that do not exist in the array and updating the ones that already exists.

Also if bucket size will be completed we need create a new document